# Does spring internally do a getBean on the property refs it needs to load?

Tags: spring

When i want a bean say in the main method I ask for a getBean on the id. Does spring container do the same when we define properties as refs to other beans within a single bean ?

Answer (score 1):

> Does spring container do the same when we define properties as refs to
>   other beans within a single bean

Ultimately yes, Spring does find beans within the application container which match your bean definition. How it does it is something which shouldn't be too much of a concern to most users. Since it's usually enough to know that if you ask for a bean from Spring it'll come wired with all of it's dependencies.

If you're interested in the exact wiring mechanism the source code is the place to learn.